# Solar Projector Optical Mechanism

Tags: optics, telescopes

I have a couple questions on the mechanism for how solar projection through a telescope works:

1. I recently took a small telescope focused at infinity, aimed it at the sun, and held a sheet of paper behind the eyepiece. It projected a focused image of the sun onto the paper. When I changed the focus away from infinity in either direction, the picture became less focused. I'm confused as to why this works since I always thought a focused telescope produces a virtual image that can never be projected onto a screen (and your eye turns it back into a real image for your retina). How can one focus setting for the telescope make an image that your eye can see and that can also be projected onto a paper?
2. If the image coming out of a telescope can be projected onto a paper, I assume it is a real image. However, I find that no matter how far or close I move the paper, the image remains in focus. I always thought that a real image is projected onto a single focal plane at a fixed distance from the lens, so how does this work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When the image is focused on infinity, then all beams are parallel, hence the distance of the screen doesn't matter.